# Confused with a statement

Tags: arrays, hex, byte

I want to check if the 4th byte of my array is equal to any of these : 0xe0 0xe1 0xe2 0xe3 0xe4 0xe5 0xe6 0xe7 0xe8 0xe9 0xeA 0xeB 0xeC 0xeD 0xeE 0xeF.
My friend told me to use the statement (array[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0.
This works but i can't actually understand why.

Comment: On wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing)#Masking_bits_to_0 and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction#Truth_table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember, with bitwise AND (`&`) operation, the Nth bit of result is only equal to 1 if both corresponding bits of the operands are equal to 1.

So &-ing `0xf0` to the value of 4th byte (`array[3]`) essentially replaces the lowest half of that byte with 0, leaving the highest one intact.

```
 1010  1010
 &
 1111  0000
 ====  ====
 1010  0000
 ^^^^  ^^^^ 
  ||    ||
as is  zeroed
```

Now all that remains is check that value against `0xe0`.

Answer (score 0):

As I was not able to understand it also, I just using the stupid long way just to make it clear for myself.

Something like this will be helpful in your case:
4th byte of your array[0] == ____ && (these_BYTEs[0] == 0xe0 || these_BYTEs[1] == 0xe1 || these_BYTEs[2] == 0xe2 || these_BYTEs[3] == 0xe3 || these_BYTEs[4] == 0xe4 || these_BYTEs[5] == 0xe5 || these_BYTEs[6] == 0xe6 || these_BYTEs[7] == 0xe7 || these_BYTEs[8] == 0xe8 || these_BYTEs[9] == 0xe9 || these_BYTEs[10] == 0xea || these_BYTEs[11] == 0xeb || these_BYTEs[12] == 0xec || these_BYTEs[13] == 0xed || these_BYTEs[14] == 0xee || these_BYTEs[15] == 0xef))

Comment: The other answer explains it quite well. I'm not clear on what this answer is trying to show.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).